# Color-coding of document entries in the navigation (custom-workflow , custom Archetypes content-type)

Tags: plone

On Plone 4.1.4 we installed a custom workflow and a custom Archetypes-based document type.
We noticed that the documents are not color-coded in the navigation (i.e. marked Red if the status is lower than published). Folders (which still use the out-of-the-box workflow) still have this functionality.

Where and how can we adapt this?

Comment: Firebug is your friend.  Almost every element (widgets, states, action menu items) has a predictable pattern for class and I naming for elements of their containing blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plone should CSS class for the navigation tree items based on its workflow state.

I think the class name was something like `state-private` where the latter part is your workflow state id.

Just add CSS styles corresponding your custom workflow states.

Comment: Great Mikko, found it on the filesystem under plonetheme/sunburst/skins/sunburst_styles/members.css.  The pattern is apparently "state-workflowstatename" . Added my workflowstates under portal_skins/custom/plonecustom.css and solved. Thanks.